# Get Facebook user Id by login Facebook account with android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-studio

I want to get Facebook user Id in android by login Facebook account. I can't get Id in right way. Please guide me, how can I get it.
My code is.

```
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code

 GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
       loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
              if (response.getError() != null) {
               // handle error
               } else {
                String name= object.optString("name");
                String id = object.optString("id");

                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
       }
    }

  }).executeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks right, this is the code i'm current using for this, maybe it helps.

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                         AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                               String email=object.optString("email");
                               String id=object.optString("id")
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "email");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }
```

Comment: this code is working correct but i want to get both name and email from user facebook id. Your code is only provide one, either name or email. How can i get both name and email at a time?

Comment: @nabiasaroosh You have to put on the request what you want. parameters.putString("fields","email,name"); then the name and email will be part of the object.  String name=object.optString("name");

Comment: waoo... brilliant. I got name, email and id at a time, which i want. Thank you.